# NoMethodError in Refinery::Blog::Posts#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs, refinery

When I want to go to "localhost:3000/blog" the web page gives this error...

```
Showing C:/Sites/ifurniture/app/views/refinery/blog/posts/index.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `to_sym' for {:title=>"Body", :slug=>"body"}:Hash

Rails.root: C:/Sites/ifurniture
```

this is the blog controller..

```
module Refinery
  module Blog
    class PostsController < BlogController

      before_filter :find_all_blog_posts, :except => [:archive]
      before_filter :find_blog_post, :only => [:show, :comment, :update_nav]
      before_filter :find_tags

      respond_to :html, :js, :rss

      def index
        if request.format.rss?
          @posts = if params["max_results"].present?
            # limit rss feed for services (like feedburner) who have max size
            Post.recent(params["max_results"])
          else
            Post.newest_first.live.includes(:comments, :categories)
          end
        end
        respond_with (@posts) do |format|
          format.html
          format.rss { render :layout => false }
        end
      end

      def show
        @comment = Comment.new

        @canonical = refinery.url_for(:locale => Refinery::I18n.current_frontend_locale) if canonical?

        @post.increment!(:access_count, 1)

        respond_with (@post) do |format|
          format.html { present(@post) }
          format.js { render :partial => 'post', :layout => false }
        end
      end

      def comment
        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
        if @comment.valid?
          if Comment::Moderation.enabled? or @comment.ham?
            begin
              CommentMailer.notification(@comment, request).deliver_now
            rescue
              logger.warn "There was an error delivering a blog comment notification.\n#{$!}\n"
            end
          end

          if Comment::Moderation.enabled?
            flash[:notice] = t('thank_you_moderated', :scope => 'refinery.blog.posts.comments')
            redirect_to refinery.blog_post_url(params[:id])
          else
            flash[:notice] = t('thank_you', :scope => 'refinery.blog.posts.comments')
            redirect_to refinery.blog_post_url(params[:id],
                                      :anchor => "comment-#{@comment.to_param}")
          end
        else
          render :show
        end
      end

      def archive
        if params[:month].present?
          date = "#{params[:month]}/#{params[:year]}"
          archive_date = Time.parse(date)
          @date_title = ::I18n.l(archive_date, :format => '%B %Y')
          @posts = Post.live.by_month(archive_date).page(params[:page])
        else
          date = "01/#{params[:year]}"
          archive_date = Time.parse(date)
          @date_title = ::I18n.l(archive_date, :format => '%Y')
          @posts = Post.live.by_year(archive_date).page(params[:page])
        end
        respond_with (@posts)
      end

      def tagged
        @tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(params[:tag_id])
        @tag_name = @tag.name
        @posts = Post.live.tagged_with(@tag_name).page(params[:page])
      end

    private

      def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :email, :message)
      end

    protected
      def canonical?
        Refinery::I18n.default_frontend_locale != Refinery::I18n.current_frontend_locale
      end
    end
  end
end
```

the post controller...

```
module Refinery
  module Blog
    class PostsController < BlogController

      before_filter :find_all_blog_posts, :except => [:archive]
      before_filter :find_blog_post, :only => [:show, :comment, :update_nav]
      before_filter :find_tags

      respond_to :html, :js, :rss

      def index
        if request.format.rss?
          @posts = if params["max_results"].present?
            # limit rss feed for services (like feedburner) who have max size
            Post.recent(params["max_results"])
          else
            Post.newest_first.live.includes(:comments, :categories)
          end
        end
        respond_with (@posts) do |format|
          format.html
          format.rss { render :layout => false }
        end
      end

      def show
        @comment = Comment.new

        @canonical = refinery.url_for(:locale => Refinery::I18n.current_frontend_locale) if canonical?

        @post.increment!(:access_count, 1)

        respond_with (@post) do |format|
          format.html { present(@post) }
          format.js { render :partial => 'post', :layout => false }
        end
      end

      def comment
        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
        if @comment.valid?
          if Comment::Moderation.enabled? or @comment.ham?
            begin
              CommentMailer.notification(@comment, request).deliver_now
            rescue
              logger.warn "There was an error delivering a blog comment notification.\n#{$!}\n"
            end
          end

          if Comment::Moderation.enabled?
            flash[:notice] = t('thank_you_moderated', :scope => 'refinery.blog.posts.comments')
            redirect_to refinery.blog_post_url(params[:id])
          else
            flash[:notice] = t('thank_you', :scope => 'refinery.blog.posts.comments')
            redirect_to refinery.blog_post_url(params[:id],
                                      :anchor => "comment-#{@comment.to_param}")
          end
        else
          render :show
        end
      end

      def archive
        if params[:month].present?
          date = "#{params[:month]}/#{params[:year]}"
          archive_date = Time.parse(date)
          @date_title = ::I18n.l(archive_date, :format => '%B %Y')
          @posts = Post.live.by_month(archive_date).page(params[:page])
        else
          date = "01/#{params[:year]}"
          archive_date = Time.parse(date)
          @date_title = ::I18n.l(archive_date, :format => '%Y')
          @posts = Post.live.by_year(archive_date).page(params[:page])
        end
        respond_with (@posts)
      end

      def tagged
        @tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(params[:tag_id])
        @tag_name = @tag.name
        @posts = Post.live.tagged_with(@tag_name).page(params[:page])
      end

    private

      def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :email, :message)
      end

    protected
      def canonical?
        Refinery::I18n.default_frontend_locale != Refinery::I18n.current_frontend_locale
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and this is the index.html.erb of Blog.

```
<section class="container">
  <% content_for :body do %>
    <%= raw @page.content_for(Refinery::Pages.default_parts.first.to_sym) if Refinery::Pages.default_parts.any? %>

    <% if @posts.any? %>
      <section id="blog_posts" class="news">
        <%= render :partial => "/refinery/blog/shared/post", :collection => @posts %>
        <%= will_paginate @posts %>
      </section>
    <% else %>
      <p><%= t('.no_blog_articles_yet') %></p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <% content_for :side_body_prepend do -%>
    <%= raw @page.content_for(Refinery::Pages.default_parts.second.to_sym) %>
  <% end if Refinery::Pages.default_parts.many? -%>

  <%= render "/refinery/content_page" %>
  <% content_for :stylesheets, stylesheet_link_tag('refinery/blog/frontend') %>
</section>
```

I'll be watching for your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `to_sym` method on hash or string so in your code you can do something like this:

### index.html

instead this:

```
<%= raw @page.content_for(Refinery::Pages.default_parts.first.to_sym) if Refinery::Pages.default_parts.any? %>
```

put this:

```
<%= raw @page.content_for(Refinery::Pages.default_parts.first[:title].to_sym) if Refinery::Pages.default_parts.any? %>
```

instead `[:title]`you can also use `[:slug]`